# Android Studio 1.3 test module (com.android.test)

Tags: android, unit-testing, gradle

The release notes from Android 1.3 state that it's now possible to have application tests under a separate module (source: http://android-developers.blogspot.ro/2015/07/get-your-hands-on-android-studio-13.html)

> For more flexibility in app testing, you now have the option to place
>   your code tests in a separate module and use the new test plugin
>   (‘com.android.test’) instead of keeping your tests right next to your
>   app code. This feature does require your app project to use the Gradle
>   Plugin 1.3

However, I haven't seen any option in AS to create such module and when I try to create one myself (first create Java library module, then alter its build.gradle file), like:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.test'

android {

    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    targetProjectPath ':app'
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

I'm getting an error:

> Error:Configuration with name 'debug-classes' not found.

Has anyone managed to get this working?

P. S. I'm using AS 1.3 with Android Gradle plugin v1.3.

Comment: I do not like this. This reminds me of the old school Eclipse "2 separate" projects for testing.

Comment: Me neither. However, it's better than constantly switching the build variants between Unit Tests and Instrumentation tests. Plus, 3rd party libs, like Dagger2, have issues generating code under the current 'test' folder.

Comment: That's a good idea. Are you going to have <app folder>/<app> and <app folder>/<appTest>? My gradle setup is for multi project so I have <apps folder>/<app1> and <apps folder>/<app2> etc. I guess I can try this configuration out.

Comment: Yes, that's how I understand it as well. However, I'm not sure if it supports only Instrumentation Tests or Unit Tests as well. Let me know if you also have this error.